# How to call csv file one by one from folder and assign the file to variable?

Tags: python, glob

I have multiple CSV files (abcd.csv, efg.csv, fdre.csv....) in the folder. Now I want to call these files one by one and pass through some program. Currently am doing something like this :

```
dir = "D:\\mobile\\card\\"
c_file_name = 'abcd.csv'
c_file = open(dir + c_file_name + '.csv', 'r')
```

I want to use some loop or something through which I can open each csv file one by one and assign to those csv's to c_file. Please suggest

Comment: `pass through some program` – what does it mean?

Comment: I have a detailed program further that work once these files are assigned to c_file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `os.walk` allows you to iterate through files in a folder. The following code is adapted from [Tutorials Point](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/os_walk.htm). In the following snippet, `dirs` is a list of directories, `files` is a list of files, and `os.path.join(root, name)` is the full filename you can use to access the file.

```py
# !/usr/bin/python

import os
for root, dirs, files in os.walk("D:\\mobile\\catd\\", topdown=False):
   for name in files:
      if name.endswith('.csv')
          c_file_name = os.path.join(root, name)
          c_file = open(c_file_name, 'r')
```

Comment: @ Andrew ..I hope it should read all the files in the folder one by one without repeating and stop the loop once all the files have been called. Am I right?

Comment: @Rahul Yes it iterates through all files in that directory.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [glob](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/glob.html#glob.glob) to get a list of all csv files inside a directory, i.e.:

```
import glob
for csv_path in glob.glob('D:\\mobile\\card\\**\\*.csv', recursive=True):
    print(csv_path) # D:\mobile\card\abcd.csv
    # do something with csv_path
```

Comment: @ Pedro..I want to assign the csv file to c_file

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by that, can you please explain what you are trying to do?

Comment: My apologies. I meant to say that I should assign csv_path (as you suggested) to my variable c_file.

Comment: `c_file  = csv_path`

Comment: Thanks. Today I learned two methods to call multiple csv files from the folder and assign it to a variable.

Comment: You're welcome, if my answer help you, please consider accepting it as the correct answer.